# Archive in Xcode appears under Other Items when i am using Unity Flutter Widget

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, unity-game-engine

When I want to distribute an iOS application that I developed using the Flutter unity widget, the following options appear. I don't see "App Store Connect" choice. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before using the tag.

Comment: I fixed my problem on this github issue : https://github.com/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget/issues/489#issuecomment-961835884